# Quickly convert simpleXMLObject to STDClass?

Tags: php, simplexml

Does anybody know a quick way to convert a SimpleXMLElement to a normal STDClass object, without iterating through each branch manually? I would feel better working with a normal object after fetching the data.

Comment: You mean importing all the public properties of that SimpleXMLElement? Quick is relative :)

Comment: You would "feel better" isn't a valid reason imo :) What's the real reason for you to want a stdClass to work with?

Comment: Well, I am fetching data from an XML file and processing it afterwards in quite a complex system. From that point I do not need any XML/SimpleXML specific behaviour, but just the raw data. PHP's XML functions tend not to be as well documented as the other parts of the language, and I fear unexpected behaviour when manipulating the data along the way with it still being a simpleXML element. With a STDClass, I know what to expect, how to manipulate it, validate the data and so on. That is the long version of "feel better". Feel better? :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest looking into using *XMLReader*, which lends itself well to extracting data and storing it as whatever data type one wishes, instead of *SimpleXML*. It's especially good for regularly-used documents (I use it, extended as *RSSReader*, for RSS), is much faster than might be expected, and as a bonus uses less memory than *SimpleXML*.

Answer (score 75):

```
$my_std_class = json_decode(json_encode($my_simplexmlelement));
$my_assoc_array = json_decode(json_encode($my_simplexmlelement), true);
```

Comment: +1, This should definitely be the chosen answer. The reason I needed to convert it to stdClass was because Drupal has issues with the SimpleXmlElement object.

Comment: Excellent! Working great :)

Comment: this results in converting SimpleXMLElement class member variables such as "MemberTypeArray" to "membertypearray" (lowercase) how do i avoid this ? and use this function to covert it to a std class ?

Answer (score 2):

Another way is:

```
(object)(array)$my_simplexmlelement
```

Unfortunately if you have children they remain as SimpleXMLElement

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there's a way to convert the object without iterating through it. My guess is that you can't.

You can check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/871422/looping-through-a-simplexml-object-or-turning-the-whole-thing-into-an-array) out, it shows you how to convert a SimpleXML to an array, you can adapt that.