# How to Loop through XML subnodes using PHP's simplexml

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

OK, I'm having trouble looping through these sub-nodes.  For this example, I'll show you the code I am using to try to grab the Amenities from a Hotel Info feed.  The XML doesn't appear to be formatted great, and unfortunately I don't have control over that.  Here's my code.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://www.2-20.com/hotelRoomSearchDetails.cfm?pnum_hotel_seq_id=210&pchr_room_type=STUDIO%22")
$hotel_amenities = $xml->contentDataResults->hotelContent->hotelAmenities;

foreach($hotel_amenities as $a){
    echo $a->amenity;
}
```

It is only returning the first amenity however.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/871422/351893

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
$hotel_amenities = $xml->contentDataResults->hotelContent->hotelAmenities->children();
foreach($hotel_amenities as $a)
{
  echo $a;
}
```

Comment: 14 years later it still works like a charm