# Parse XML in PHP error

Tags: php, xml, parsing

in the past I loaded the xmlfile with `<station></station>` Tags and did a foreach loop like this

```
foreach ( $xml->station as $item )
{
...
}>
```

Now I got a new structure like this and it doesn't work anymore.
Can you help me, please?

```
<stations>
<station id="1" name="Raumschiff1" strasse="Musterstrasse 1" plz="11011" ort="Berlin" lat="50.77548" lng="6.08147" operator="NEO" telefon="0800 MATRIX" zugang="ZION"/>

<station id="2" name="Raumschiff1" strasse="Musterstrasse 1" plz="11011" ort="Berlin" lat="50.77548" lng="6.08147" operator="NEO" telefon="0800 MATRIX" zugang="ZION"/>
</stations>
```

Thanks a lot in advance! :-)

Comment: 1) Any errors?  2) Will you post any code?  3) XML yoy posted is not valid xml. It has no `<?xml ...` line

Comment: In the past you haved same file but without `<stations>` tag ?

Comment: I cannot post the complete XML-File because it has a size of 1MB, so its very big.

This was only a small snapshot of the XML file. The original file beginns with <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 

I download the file from a customer from us, and in the past the XML File was with <station></station> and now it is with <station id>/>

Answer (score 0):

- added simplexml_load_string()
- if you need to load a file `$xml = simplexml_load_file('test.xml');`
- added xml doctype line missing.

Example below:

```
$xml_string = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<stations>
  <station id="1" name="Raumschiff1" strasse="Musterstrasse 1" plz="11011" ort="Berlin" lat="50.77548" lng="6.08147" operator="NEO" telefon="0800 MATRIX" zugang="ZION" />
  <station id="2" name="Raumschiff2" strasse="Musterstrasse 1" plz="11011" ort="Berlin" lat="50.77548" lng="6.08147" operator="NEO" telefon="0800 MATRIX" zugang="ZION" />
</stations>';

$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml_string);    
//print_r($xml);

// iterate over the SimpleXMLElement Object    
foreach($xml->station as $station) {

    // you need to take the attributes into account
    foreach ($station->attributes() as $attributeName => $attributeValue) {
        printf("\n%s => %s", $attributeName, $attributeValue);
    }

    echo "<hr>";
}
```

---

And your next question is: "How to iterate that object or array?"

Already answered:

- [How to iterate through XML values that are a SimpleXMLElement Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9321148/how-to-iterate-through-xml-values-that-are-a-simplexmlelement-object)
- [Looping through a SimpleXML object, or turning the whole thing into an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/871422/looping-through-a-simplexml-object-or-turning-the-whole-thing-into-an-array?lq=1)

Comment: Now I got this output

   

     [stations] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [station] => Array (    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [id] => 2 [name] => Raumschiff 1 [strasse] => Musterstrasse 1 [plz] => 11011 [ort] => Berlin [lat] => 11.11111 [lng] => 0.08147 [operator] => NEO [telefon] => 0800 11111


Now I tried to access the attributes with

    foreach ( $array->station->id as $item )

but it doesnt work.

Comment: That's simply an iteration of the values of an object or array. I've updated my answer accordingly.